# Horizontal align text and &:after image inside button

Tags: html, css, less, flexbox

I have the next button: `<button className="my-button">Deposit</button>`

Besides the `"Deposit"` text it should have a deposit picture. I add it with `&:after` trick. It looks like:

[image]

**Problem:** get the result below. Of cource I can align `deposit.png` to right place, but I can't shift button text.

[image]

**Question:** *how to align `Deposit` text and `deposit.png` inside button without extra wrappers (only with css)?*

**My css:**

```
button.my-button {
  position: relative;
  width: 125px;
  height: 40px;
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid fade(white, 70);
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: Proxima Nova Soft semibold, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: white;
  &:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 19px;
    height: 16px;
    border: none;
    background: url('../assets/images/deposit.png') no-repeat;
  }
}
```

**My workarounds:**

Tried to use flex-box, but it seems don't work for `button`s

Comment: The question is there but I am failing to see a problem here, what is it you want to achieve? (what exactly is it not doing what you want it to do?)

Comment: Aren't you just looking for the background-position property? Is your image the actual outcome, or it is the thing you want to achieve? If it's the thing you want to achieve, how is it looking right now?

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand updated

Comment: @SteynvanEsveld no, because background-position doesn't align button text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> .my-button:after {display: inline-block; /* you have given it
>   display:block - which makes it fall in next line*/ }

```css
body {
  background: #333
}
.my-button {
  position: relative;
  width: 125px;
  height: 40px;
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: Proxima Nova Soft semibold, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: white;
}
.my-button:after {
  content: "";
  vertical-align:middle;
  display: inline-block;
  /* you have given it display:block - which makes it fall in next line*/
  width: 19px;
  height: 16px;
  border: none;
  background: url('https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ledicons/money_pound.png') left top no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<button class="my-button">Deposit</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

I made a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sz8Lwfgo/) that does what you need. You need to make the `:after` element `display: inline-block;`, and **not** make it `position: absolute;`. Making it `position: absolute;` will take it out of the 'flow'

Comment: You beat me to it! My answer explains how and why ;)

Answer (score 2):

All that before and after does is toggle an extra element before or after the **contents** of an element, wether these contents are other html elements or text doesn't matter.

By making your image `position: relative` with no `top`, `bottom`, `left` or `right` defined and a simple `display: inline-block` it will act as text.

Since you used the `:after` psuedo selector the element is obviously placed after the text and all you'd need to do now is space it from the text and possibly center it vertically.

You can use `vertical-align: middle` to center it vertically (since this image is represented as text through `display: inline-block`)

After that you can space the element using `margin-left` since `inline-block` elements are allowed to have margin. (tho `padding` will also work just fine but in this context, margin is the better choice)

This will also cause your image to move when the text gets longer (unless you set a specific width/height which would clip or wrap the image ofcourse).

The reason margin > padding in this context is because you're spacing **between** nodes and not spacing contents **within** a node (that's the idea anyways - see it as adding a whitespace with margin)

Hope this helps, if you need more information feel free to ask ofcourse.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your code and add just 3 lines of code, display doesn't have to be inline-block.

```
button:after {
  right: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -8px;
}
```

Comment: This is definitely a solution but do not forget that if you wish to make more changes this code will just get hackier and hackier ;)

Comment: @makshh this code also doesn't align a button text - so you will miss pixel-perfect distance between button text & button :after image